# How to use pywinauto and selenium for login purpose?

Tags: python, selenium, pywinauto

I tried to write code to login using pywinauto and selenium, but my script is getting failed. I tried to find solution, but it seems there is no much info available on this.

```
from pywinauto import application
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
app=application.Application()
driver.get("https://google.co.in")//url for google only as an example 
app = application.Application()
app.connect(backend="uia") // getting issue in this line, what to write under bracket to connect to opened browser?
app.window_().TypeKeys('username') // Is this proper way to type text in authentication window username field where cursor blinks by default?
```

I am getting below error message

> pywinauto.findwindows.ElementAmbiguousError: There are 6 elements that
>   match the criteria {'backend': u'win32'}

**Note :** For login to my application, windows authentication popup appears which cannot be handled in selenium, so need to handle it using other tool. I had a solution to it earlier which is not working now, I had asked it here [Windows authentication code no longer working now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491048/windows-authentication-code-no-longer-working-now)

Comment: Why use pywinauto when selenium does button clicks and typing functions.

Comment: For login to my application, windows authentication popup appears which cannot be handled in selenium, so need to handle it using other tool. I had a solution to it earlier which is not working now, I had asked it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491048/windows-authentication-code-no-longer-working-now?noredirect=1#comment86235945_49491048

Comment: Does `app = application.Application(backend="uia").connect(path="chrome.exe")` work?

Answer (score 0):

The steps your need are; open the page, find the elements you want to interact with (such as login text box) then type your input. This can all be done in selenium. Check out the documentation:
 http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#interacting-with-the-page

Comment: For login to my application, windows authentication popup appears which cannot be handled in selenium, so need to handle it using other tool. I had a solution to it earlier which is not working now, I had asked it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491048/windows-authentication-code-no-longer-working-now?noredirect=1#comment86235945_49491048

Comment: No, need to search. It would be better if you provide any link to it which works for me